# How can I generate a receipt UUID in Oracle SQL using SHA256 and convert it to a hexadecimal string of 64 characters?

Tags: sql, oracle, plsql, uuid, sha256

**I'm trying to integrate with Egypt EInvoicing , EReceipt , I should generate receipt UUID and to do that I should follow instructions in this link https://sdk.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/receiptissuancefaq/#how-to-generate-receipt-uuid
I did steps 1,2,3,4 But for Step 5 I should Create a hash value of the normalized text using SHA256 so i used this sql
**

```
SELECT STANDARD_HASH(
('"HEADER""DATETIMEISSUED""2023-05-25T00:34:00Z""RECEIPTNUMBER""001""UUID""""PREVIOUSUUID""""REFERENCEOLDUUID""""CURRENCY""EGP""EXCHANGERATE""0""SORDERNAMECODE""sOrderNameCode""ORDERDELIVERYMODE""""GROSSWEIGHT""6.58""NETWEIGHT""6.89""DOCUMENTTYPE""RECEIPTTYPE""S""TYPEVERSION""1.2""SELLER""RIN""100334776""COMPANYTRADENAME""Minapharm""BRANCHCODE""0""BRANCHADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""cairo""REGIONCITY""city center""STREET""16 street""BUILDINGNUMBER""14BN""POSTALCODE""74235""FLOOR""1F""ROOM""3R""LANDMARK""tahrir square""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""talaat harb street""DEVICESERIALNUMBER""Sofy123""SYNDICATELICENSENUMBER""1000056""ACTIVITYCODE""4620""BUYER""TYPE""F""ID""313717919""NAME""taxpayer 1""MOBILENUMBER""+201020567462""PAYMENTNUMBER""987654""ITEMDATA""ITEMDATA""INTERNALCODE""880609""DESCRIPTION""Samsung A02 32GB_LTE_BLACK_DS_SM-A022FZKDMEB_A022 _ A022_SM-A022FZKDMEB""ITEMTYPE""GS1""ITEMCODE""037000401629""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""35""UNITPRICE""247.96000""NETSALE""7810.74000""TOTALSALE""8678.60000""TOTAL""8887.04360""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""867.86000""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""ABC""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""VALUEDIFFERENCE""20""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""SUBTYPE""V009""RATE""14""TOTALSALES""8678.60000""TOTALCOMMERCIALDISCOUNT""867.86000""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNT""20""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""0""DESCRIPTION""ABC""NETAMOUNT""7810.74000""FEESAMOUNT""0""TOTALAMOUNT""8887.04360""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""PAYMENTMETHOD""C""ADJUSTMENT""0""CONTRACTOR""NAME""contractor1""AMOUNT""2.563""RATE""2.3""BENEFICIARY""AMOUNT""20.569""RATE""2.147"')
,'SHA256') as standard_hash_SHA256
FROM DUAL;
```

**and The Result I Got Was **`E1F20DB1DB2C79B84C823CFB0F9B8C89BF3FAD367CD732CEFB3E9AEAFD2E3F8B`

**and here I have two questions :
The 1st Question : In Step Number 6 They Said "Convert the hash value from array of 32 bytes to hexadecimal string of 64 characters"
But I Already Got The 64 Character when I run The previous SQL
The 2nd Question : On Their Application The rsult of the SQL should be **`65e952fae3e93f64441433bb72eaa6d4d038945fc132e6e8ae3d3444c5d26a50`

**with LiveSQL Test Case:
**`https://livesql.oracle.com/apex/livesql/s/o8fmjsynr77byq5fg1vkelwcg`

**So please advise what i have to do to get the same result for uuid for the data in the above SQL
**

Comment: What do you mean by "On Their Application The rsult of the SQL should be ..." - what application, and where did you get that 65e952... value from? Is some other tool generating that from exactly the same source string?

Answer (score 0):

> In Step Number 6 They Said "Convert the hash value from array of 32 bytes to hexadecimal string of 64 characters" But I Already Got The 64 Character when I run The previous SQL

No, you didn't. [The STANDARD_HASH function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/STANDARD_HASH.html) returns a RAW value. Some clients, including SQL Live it seems, display a text equivalent. In db<>fiddle the value is displayed as `0xE1F20D...` with the `0x` prefix indicating it it's a decoded hex value.

```
SELECT STANDARD_HASH( 
                    ('"HEADER""DATETIMEISSUED""2023-05-25T00:34:00Z""RECEIPTNUMBER""001""UUID""""PREVIOUSUUID""""REFERENCEOLDUUID""""CURRENCY""EGP""EXCHANGERATE""0""SORDERNAMECODE""sOrderNameCode""ORDERDELIVERYMODE""""GROSSWEIGHT""6.58""NETWEIGHT""6.89""DOCUMENTTYPE""RECEIPTTYPE""S""TYPEVERSION""1.2""SELLER""RIN""100334776""COMPANYTRADENAME""Minapharm""BRANCHCODE""0""BRANCHADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""cairo""REGIONCITY""city center""STREET""16 street""BUILDINGNUMBER""14BN""POSTALCODE""74235""FLOOR""1F""ROOM""3R""LANDMARK""tahrir square""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""talaat harb street""DEVICESERIALNUMBER""Sofy123""SYNDICATELICENSENUMBER""1000056""ACTIVITYCODE""4620""BUYER""TYPE""F""ID""313717919""NAME""taxpayer 1""MOBILENUMBER""+201020567462""PAYMENTNUMBER""987654""ITEMDATA""ITEMDATA""INTERNALCODE""880609""DESCRIPTION""Samsung A02 32GB_LTE_BLACK_DS_SM-A022FZKDMEB_A022 _ A022_SM-A022FZKDMEB""ITEMTYPE""GS1""ITEMCODE""037000401629""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""35""UNITPRICE""247.96000""NETSALE""7810.74000""TOTALSALE""8678.60000""TOTAL""8887.04360""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""867.86000""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""ABC""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""VALUEDIFFERENCE""20""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""SUBTYPE""V009""RATE""14""TOTALSALES""8678.60000""TOTALCOMMERCIALDISCOUNT""867.86000""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNT""20""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""0""DESCRIPTION""ABC""NETAMOUNT""7810.74000""FEESAMOUNT""0""TOTALAMOUNT""8887.04360""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""PAYMENTMETHOD""C""ADJUSTMENT""0""CONTRACTOR""NAME""contractor1""AMOUNT""2.563""RATE""2.3""BENEFICIARY""AMOUNT""20.569""RATE""2.147"') 
                    ,'SHA256') as standard_hash_SHA256  
        FROM DUAL
```

| STANDARD_HASH_SHA256 |
| --- |
| 0xE1F20DB1DB2C79B84C823CFB0F9B8C89BF3FAD367CD732CEFB3E9AEAFD2E3F8B |

You can use [the RAWTOHEX function](https://docs.oracle.com/en/database/oracle/oracle-database/19/sqlrf/RAWTOHEX.html) to actually convert it to a string:

```
SELECT RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH( 
                    ('"HEADER""DATETIMEISSUED""2023-05-25T00:34:00Z""RECEIPTNUMBER""001""UUID""""PREVIOUSUUID""""REFERENCEOLDUUID""""CURRENCY""EGP""EXCHANGERATE""0""SORDERNAMECODE""sOrderNameCode""ORDERDELIVERYMODE""""GROSSWEIGHT""6.58""NETWEIGHT""6.89""DOCUMENTTYPE""RECEIPTTYPE""S""TYPEVERSION""1.2""SELLER""RIN""100334776""COMPANYTRADENAME""Minapharm""BRANCHCODE""0""BRANCHADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""cairo""REGIONCITY""city center""STREET""16 street""BUILDINGNUMBER""14BN""POSTALCODE""74235""FLOOR""1F""ROOM""3R""LANDMARK""tahrir square""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""talaat harb street""DEVICESERIALNUMBER""Sofy123""SYNDICATELICENSENUMBER""1000056""ACTIVITYCODE""4620""BUYER""TYPE""F""ID""313717919""NAME""taxpayer 1""MOBILENUMBER""+201020567462""PAYMENTNUMBER""987654""ITEMDATA""ITEMDATA""INTERNALCODE""880609""DESCRIPTION""Samsung A02 32GB_LTE_BLACK_DS_SM-A022FZKDMEB_A022 _ A022_SM-A022FZKDMEB""ITEMTYPE""GS1""ITEMCODE""037000401629""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""35""UNITPRICE""247.96000""NETSALE""7810.74000""TOTALSALE""8678.60000""TOTAL""8887.04360""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""867.86000""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""ABC""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""VALUEDIFFERENCE""20""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""SUBTYPE""V009""RATE""14""TOTALSALES""8678.60000""TOTALCOMMERCIALDISCOUNT""867.86000""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNT""20""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""0""DESCRIPTION""ABC""NETAMOUNT""7810.74000""FEESAMOUNT""0""TOTALAMOUNT""8887.04360""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""PAYMENTMETHOD""C""ADJUSTMENT""0""CONTRACTOR""NAME""contractor1""AMOUNT""2.563""RATE""2.3""BENEFICIARY""AMOUNT""20.569""RATE""2.147"') 
                    ,'SHA256')) as standard_hash_SHA256  
        FROM DUAL
```

| STANDARD_HASH_SHA256 |
| --- |
| E1F20DB1DB2C79B84C823CFB0F9B8C89BF3FAD367CD732CEFB3E9AEAFD2E3F8B |

And if the case matters you can convert it to lower-case:

```
SELECT LOWER(RAWTOHEX(STANDARD_HASH( 
                    ('"HEADER""DATETIMEISSUED""2023-05-25T00:34:00Z""RECEIPTNUMBER""001""UUID""""PREVIOUSUUID""""REFERENCEOLDUUID""""CURRENCY""EGP""EXCHANGERATE""0""SORDERNAMECODE""sOrderNameCode""ORDERDELIVERYMODE""""GROSSWEIGHT""6.58""NETWEIGHT""6.89""DOCUMENTTYPE""RECEIPTTYPE""S""TYPEVERSION""1.2""SELLER""RIN""100334776""COMPANYTRADENAME""Minapharm""BRANCHCODE""0""BRANCHADDRESS""COUNTRY""EG""GOVERNATE""cairo""REGIONCITY""city center""STREET""16 street""BUILDINGNUMBER""14BN""POSTALCODE""74235""FLOOR""1F""ROOM""3R""LANDMARK""tahrir square""ADDITIONALINFORMATION""talaat harb street""DEVICESERIALNUMBER""Sofy123""SYNDICATELICENSENUMBER""1000056""ACTIVITYCODE""4620""BUYER""TYPE""F""ID""313717919""NAME""taxpayer 1""MOBILENUMBER""+201020567462""PAYMENTNUMBER""987654""ITEMDATA""ITEMDATA""INTERNALCODE""880609""DESCRIPTION""Samsung A02 32GB_LTE_BLACK_DS_SM-A022FZKDMEB_A022 _ A022_SM-A022FZKDMEB""ITEMTYPE""GS1""ITEMCODE""037000401629""UNITTYPE""EA""QUANTITY""35""UNITPRICE""247.96000""NETSALE""7810.74000""TOTALSALE""8678.60000""TOTAL""8887.04360""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""COMMERCIALDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""867.86000""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""ABC""ITEMDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""10""DESCRIPTION""XYZ""VALUEDIFFERENCE""20""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXABLEITEMS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""SUBTYPE""V009""RATE""14""TOTALSALES""8678.60000""TOTALCOMMERCIALDISCOUNT""867.86000""TOTALITEMSDISCOUNT""20""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""EXTRARECEIPTDISCOUNTDATA""AMOUNT""0""DESCRIPTION""ABC""NETAMOUNT""7810.74000""FEESAMOUNT""0""TOTALAMOUNT""8887.04360""TAXTOTALS""TAXTOTALS""TAXTYPE""T1""AMOUNT""1096.30360""PAYMENTMETHOD""C""ADJUSTMENT""0""CONTRACTOR""NAME""contractor1""AMOUNT""2.563""RATE""2.3""BENEFICIARY""AMOUNT""20.569""RATE""2.147"') 
                    ,'SHA256'))) as standard_hash_SHA256  
        FROM DUAL
```

| STANDARD_HASH_SHA256 |
| --- |
| e1f20db1db2c79b84c823cfb0f9b8c89bf3fad367cd732cefb3e9aeafd2e3f8b |

[fiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/h09Nb7Br)

Comment: Thanks for your kind reply , but I have to find way to get the right UUID it should be this result `65e952fae3e93f64441433bb72eaa6d4d038945fc132e6e8ae3d3444c5d26a50` not this result `e1f20db1db2c79b84c823cfb0f9b8c89bf3fad367cd732cefb3e9aeafd2e3f8b`

Comment: That is the correct hash for that string. Why do you think it should be something different? And are you sure the string you generated is right?

Comment: Hello alex, Thank for your reply.. I dont think but the egyptian Tax Ereceipt Doesnt Submit the receipt and always give me error that (Valid UUID Is Required)

Comment: And When i return to them they give me different UUID that submit successfully When i use and that function always give me different UUID, So i still could not to integrate with them till Now because UUID Is Mandatory

Comment: Are they generating it from the same string, or from the original XML or JSON value? if it's from the same string then they need to explain how/why they get a different hash. If it's from the original then they are manipulating it differently; examine the rules again, check all the names and array handling, and again ask them what they are doing differently - or even what string value they generate before hashing so you can compare that with yours. You can't tell anything just by looking at the two hashes.

Comment: Actually They generate the canonical serialize from JSON Then they convert using SHA256 Then they transfer the value to 64bit as they said in this documentation https://sdk.invoicing.eta.gov.eg/document-serialization-approach/

Comment: Then the way you are serializing the JSON is not the same as their canonical approach. The simplest thing is for them to give you the canonical string so you can compare it and work out where you differ. You haven't shown your JSON or your serialization code, so we can't tell you where you might be going wrong. (But adding it to this question wouldn't be appropriate, you shouldn't ask two things in one question; if you can't figure it out then ask a new question showing your JSON and code.)